# Getting CSS Tooltips with iFrames to work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, tooltip

I've been trying to get CSS tooltips with iFrames working cross-browser, but Chrome has issues.

Here's a test page I put together: http://paulleduc.com/test.html

As you can see, it works as expected in FF and IE, with the tooltip popping up to the right of the word every time. In Chrome however, the tooltip pops up at the left of the screen most of the time, and only popping in the correct position when you hover over the words from 'left-to-right' it seems.

Any ideas to get this working in Chrome would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the tooltip version you are using specifically. BUT, I use this one

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/popinfo.htm

and I have no problem with it working on chrome or FF, it has worked on every browser I have tested it on, it also comes with really good instructions.

And I am not sure if it is supposed to be this way, but when I hover over your links it just opens a small square and I can see the google homepage.

But seriously, the one that i posted above DHTML Tool Tips, works really well cross browser, let me know how it works out if you decide to use it.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately for my purposes I need the code to be very minimal, without using frameworks, as the tooltips are essentially going to be inserted in any webpage via a javascript that I host.

Comment: And the squares you see with the google homepage inside them are the test iframes I am using in the tooltips. Viewing the source reveals that the tooltip code is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the latest version of Chrome. I'm using Chrome 17.0.942.0 (Official Build 110446) dev-m and cannot reproduce the issue - the tooltips pop up immediately to the right of the links. However, their contents are empty due to the "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." error (which I believe is unrelated.)